# isuue with getting json data with dart

Tags: json, api, http, dart, flutter

I use code in dart to get api data.
Code doesn't' show any error also it didn't response data.

API link : https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

environment:
  `sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"`

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http: any

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() async {
    List _data =  await getJSON();
    print("hello world ");
    runApp(
    new MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Jason Pddarsin"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
          centerTitle: true,
        ),

        body: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: _data.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int pos) {
              return Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Divider(
                    height: 5.5,
                  ),
                  Text(_data[pos]["name"]),
                ],
              );
            }),
      ),
     ),
    );
    }

    Future<List> getJSON() async {
    String apiUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";
    http.Response response = await http.get(apiUrl);
    return json.decode(response.body);
}
```

If I use that code directly mobile get white screen, I use a simple app to run `materialapp` then add this to my code and it doesn't' show any data.

Answer (score 0):

I just copied and pasted your code on a brand new flutter project and it worked fine. Do you get any kind of error messages? You said you put this inside another MaterialApp? If that is the case, try to call this from your main directly and not inside a MaterialApp. 
 [image]